# How to drag image at mouse movement angle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a mouse vector image on a dark gray background that I can drag around the page once clicked from the left side. I would like the mouse to rotate towards the cursor's direction.

With what I have so far, the mouse rotates towards the cursors direction when I bring the cursor down or right. It does not work properly when going up or left.

I have seen somewhere that atan assumes the coordinate system is +x right and +y up. I am unsure of how to proceed from there.

I have inserted my code below and replaced the image with a white rectangle.

```js
var click_degrees;
        const $dial = $('#item');
        const radius = $dial.outerWidth();
        const center_x = $dial.offset().left + radius;
        const center_y = $dial.offset().top + radius;

        function get_degrees(mouse_x, mouse_y) {

            const radians = Math.atan2(mouse_y - center_y, mouse_x - center_x);
            const degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI);

            return degrees;
        }

        var dragItem = document.querySelector("#item");

        var active = false;
        var currentX;
        var currentY;
        var initialX;
        var initialY;
        var xOffset = 0;
        var yOffset = 0;


        container.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
        container.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
        container.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);

        function dragStart(e) {
            click_degrees = get_degrees(e.pageX, e.pageY);
            initialX = e.clientX - xOffset;
            initialY = e.clientY - yOffset;
            if (e.target === dragItem) {
                active = true;
            }
        }

        function dragEnd(e) {
            initialX = currentX;
            initialY = currentY;

            active = false;
        }

        function drag(e) {
            if (active) {

                e.preventDefault();
                const degrees = get_degrees(e.pageX, e.pageY) - click_degrees;
                currentX = e.clientX - initialX;
                currentY = e.clientY - initialY;

                xOffset = currentX;
                yOffset = currentY;

                setTranslate(currentX, currentY, dragItem, degrees);
            }
        }

        function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el, deg) {
            el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0) rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
        }
```

```css
#container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 1000px;
            background-color: #333;
            overflow: hidden;
            touch-action: none;
        }

        #item {
            touch-action: none;
            user-select: none;
            transform-origin: 0 50%;
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            background:#fff;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
        initial-scale=1.0, 
        user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Drag/Drop/Bounce</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="outerContainer">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please let me know if you would like for me to clarify anything or if I should add more information.

Comment: please checkout [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Jaydeep_Mor/uh05ftxv/97/) fiddle is this what you want or tell me if anything should to do.

Comment: @JaydeepMor Hi, thank you for your response. That is not exactly what I want to do. I would like to be able (once clicked) to drag the rectangle from the left side and for the rectangle to "rotate" torwards the cursors direction. Kind of like the last demo on https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-natural-simulations/programming-angular-movement/a/pointing-towards-movement but in javascript/jquery, no circling around the cursor when the cursor stops moving and having to click and then drag to trigger. Does that clear it up?

Comment: okay so if I get you properly you need to drag rectangle from left to right with `rotate` transform right ?